# Using tortoise for existing project

Tags: eclipse, tortoisesvn, commit

my project is connected to svn repository by eclipse plugin, and by tortoise, i used to checkout and update my code from both tools, the problem appeared when i needed to update tortoise, now i cant find any thing related to tortoise in the context menu from windows, its like i need to download the project again with tortoise .... is there any way to do it without re download the code... (i have many changes and cant commit from eclipse, need to use tortoise).

Comment: did you try clean command? If so what does it say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout to a new directory, replace the files you need to update on the repository and then do the commit, that might be the easiest and safest way.

Comment: the problem is that when clicking right click tortoise doesn't appear in context menu.. in any folder.. just noticed that.. maybe i need to restart the machine

Comment: Ah so that's an installation problem, try to restart or reinstall tortoise then.